# Want an instance df = MyClass() to be a pandas data frame displayed typing df

Tags: python, pandas, inheritance

It is a beginner's question. I would like to write a class which inherits from pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

class MyClass(pd.DataFrame):
    # my code
```

An instance

```
df = MyClass()
```

should be a data frame returned by `pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')`
and I would like it displays when simply typing

```
df
```

under iPython, and, of course, with all methods of pd.DataFrame working (except `__init__` which I need to rewrite). I have no idea how to obtain the required behaviour. All my attempts have failed.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a factory function, not a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

An `__init__` and `super` functions are what you are seeking:

```py
class MyClass(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self,file_name = 'myfile.csv'):
        super().__init__(pd.read_csv(file_name))
        #python 3
```

What are [__init__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) and [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)? Click to find out(python docs).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for. Your answer is the first example I've ever seen without `self` in the left hand side of an assignment in the body of customized `__init__`. I am trying to understand what is the rule for

           `df = MyClass()`

to work here. Is it that the evaluation of the last expression in the body of `__init__` is taken as the instance reference assigned to `df`?